# iPhone:how to display iAd banner in Dapp exported code navigation based

Tags: iphone, iad, navigationcontroller, banner

I wasn't able to display the banner using dapp exported code which looks like it's navigation based I have followed through many samples including iadsuites sample from apple (navigation based) but there's no display of banner anywhere no matter where I put the position of the banner. I understand navigationcontroller takes up the whole screen which I'm assuming which is why it wasn't able to display the banner. I would like to get sample, tutor , help to be able to display the banner. Thanks =)

I have no xib and everything is done programmatically!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tutorial may help you:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1371/how-to-integrate-iad-into-your-iphone-app

The key to getting it to work in a UIViewCotroller is this from the article:

> What we’re going to need to do with iAd is scroll an ad view onto the
>   screen when an ad     is available, and shrink the rest of the content
>   to fill the remaining space. As currently designed, this isn’t that
>   easy because all of the controls are direct children of the root view.
>   But there’s an easy way to fix it – we’ll simply move the controls
>   into a subview instead!

If it's a navigation based app, the rootController would be  UIViewController.  I believe you'll need to put all your views inside a containing view so you can resize it and animate in the iAD.

Comment: Thanks for your time but I also tried that and bees4honey and both still not displaying the banner